# How to access a foreign key field in a sqlite model?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite

I'm working in an auction web app in Django. I'm designing the database and would like to reference the username attribute from User() model in my Listing() model.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    ## some fields
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="listing")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Owner: @{self.owner.username}"
```

The User class, in AbstractUser there is a username field, i checked. But somehow I'm getting this error:
`'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'username'`

Comment: There can be many "owners" per `Listing` as you're using a `ManyToManyField`

Comment: THis has nothing to do with Sqlite. The problem is that `owner` is not a `ForeignKey`, it is a `ManyToManyField`. This thus means that `self.owner` is a manager for a `ManyToManyField`. There can thus be zero, one, or many `User`s that are the `owner`(s).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: So if there is only one owner per listing should i make it only  ForeignKey? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @nicoleitor: yes. A `ForeignKey` means it refers to *exactly* one object.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Please make an answer so I can accept it @WillemVanOnsem